# Compiling a Fortran mex file with CMake

Tags: cmake, fortran, mex

I have a Fortran project that I've compiled into mex. It has a bunch of Fortran files that have to be linked together, and some mex libraries. Using a Makefile like the one below, I was able to get this to work:

```
MEX=/opt/matlab/r2018a/bin/mex

FORTRAN = gfortran
FFLAGS = -c -fpic -fopenmp -Wall -O3 -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8
MEXLIBDIR = /opt/matlab/r2018a/sys/os/glnxa64
MEXLIB = -lgfortran -liomp5 -lirc -lsvml -limf 

OBJS=\
file_a.o\
file_b.o\

all: file_a file_b mex

mex: mex_executable.F $(OBJS) 
    $(MEX) -v -O mex_exectuable.F $(OBJS) -L$(MEXLIBDIR) $(MEXLIB)

file_a: file_a.f
    $(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) file_a.f

file_b: file_b.f
    $(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) file_b.f
```

Since I'll have several projects like this, I'd like to put everything into a single CMake file.

So far, I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that looks something like this, inside a build directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MEX)

enable_language(Fortran)

find_package(Matlab REQUIRED MAIN_PROGRAM MX_LIBRARY)    
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/")

# Assuming gfortran
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "-c -fpic -Wall -O3  -fopenmp -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8")

include_directories(
  ${Matlab_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Add modules with MEX to be built
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Project1")
```

And inside the Project1 directory I have, another `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

## MEX functions
matlab_add_mex(
    NAME mex_executable
    SRC mex_executable.F *.f
)
target_link_libraries(mex_executable lgfortran liomp5 lirc lsvml limf )
```

When I run the CMake I get the error:

```
Cannot find source file:

    *.f

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

What is the correct way to tell CMake to compile the Fortran files and link the correct mex libraries?

Answer (score 1):

This error likely results from the arguments provided to the [`matlab_add_mex()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindMatlab.html#command:matlab_add_mex) command here:

```
matlab_add_mex(
    NAME mex_executable
    SRC mex_executable.F *.f
)
```

The `SRC` argument accepts a *list* of source files, and likely cannot resolve the `*.f` provided. It would be best to list each file individually:

```
matlab_add_mex(
    NAME mex_executable
    SRC mex_executable.F file_a.f file_b.f
)
```

Or, you can use CMake's [`GLOB`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem) to create a list of `.f` source files, and use that list instead:

```
file(GLOB FORTRAN_SRCS_LIST *.f)
matlab_add_mex(
    NAME mex_executable
    SRC mex_executable.F ${FORTRAN_SRCS_LIST}
)
```

Comment: Ok, I did as you suggested, but I think first that file_a and file_b should be compiled to .o files. I tried doing that by adding  

`add_executable  (file_a "file_a.f")`  
`add_executable  (file_b "file_b.f")`  

 and then calling `SRC mex_executable.F file_a.o file_b.o` in the matlab_add_mex This gives the warning `linker input file unused because linking not done` I think this is because I'm using the -c flag when I invoke Fortran, and I only want to call it when I'm compiling the .o files. Is it possible remove the -c flag when I'm compiling the mex file?

P.S. sorry about format

Comment: Let me know if you think this is worth asking as a separate question, or altering my original one

Comment: @LukasBystricky I'm not too familiar with compiling Fortran using CMake. However, your issue seems to stem from the fact that you are manually manipulating the `CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS`, which is discouraged in modern versions of CMake. This is because the flags would apply to **several** targets. You should prefer to use the `target_compile_options()` command when possible, to only apply compile flags to a *specific* target, and ensure they don't bleed into other compilations unnecessarily.